# turtlebot kinect power

Tags: ros, irobot-create, serial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I was trying to test out the board on my turtlebot (I don't have ROS setup yet but I should have access to my computers soon). I am only using serial commands over realterm. I used a crimping tool, cut out the power-adapter from the Y-splitter and connected the red/brown wires as shown in the manual and plugged them in (as [pic1](http://shriphani.com/IMG_0975.JPG) [pic2](http://shriphani.com/IMG_0974.JPG))

I then set the create to Full mode via realterm but the kinect isn't powered on at all (blinking green light). Can anyone help me power the kinect using just OI (I don't have a laptop to run ROS on atm and I would really like to see if I have any defective hardware.

Thanks,
Shriphani P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32322/turtlebot-kinect-power/) by [shriphani](https://answers.ros.org/users/2222/shriphani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect requires both USB and 12V power to operate.

You should get a multimeter and measure the voltage on the power connector to confirm that it is producing 12V.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-25**:
I am having problem while connecting the kinect power using DB25 connector of Irobot create base. The connector circuit is designed by clearpath robotics to provide 12V DC power to kinect by taking power from pin 10 and 14 of DB25 connector of irobot create base.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-07-26**:
please ask a new question.

**Comment by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on 2013-07-26**:
I have asked the question with more detailed information.... need you help.
pls visit question here ........ 
http://answers.ros.org/question/67618/kinect-power-problem-while-connecting-to-the-irobot-create-base/